# Execute Multiple Command Using Batch File and install MySQL using batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd, window

I'm trying it write a window batch file to perform several tasks in series, However, it always stops after tie first command in the script.
I am use this this batch file code:

```
start cmd /k cd %CD%mysql\bin && mysqld --install
```

I want to use this batch file command and install the MySQL but it run only only one command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following command in your batch file:

```
start cmd /k cd %CD%mysql\bin && mysqld --install
```

Lets break it down into smaller pieces.

- `start` start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)
- `cmd /k cd %CD%mysql\bin` run `cd %CD%mysql\bin and then return to the cmd prompt.
- `&&` if the above succeeds then run the next command
- `mysqld --install` run `mysqld --install` if `start cmd /k cd %CD%mysql\bin` succeeded

The second part will never run as the first part **returned to the command prompt**.

Try the following batch file instead:

```
cd %CD%mysql\bin
mysqld --install
```

Note the variable CD must be assigned a sensible value, otherwise `cd %CD%mysql\bin` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a lot of layers here: both `start` and `cmd /c` (which I think you'd prefer over `cmd /k` for use in a batch file).

What's wrong with just `cd %CD%\mysql\bin && mysqld --install`? This worked fine for me when I attempted to run notepad.exe thus: `cd /d %WINDIR%\System32 && notepad` (note the additional '\' character here, just in case ... an extra backslash won't hurt if env var CD already has one). For that matter, I'll bet `%CD%\mysql\bin\mysqld --install` would work just fine.

However, just in case you want the extra cruft – or, more likely, need it for some other functionality you're not showing. Using just `cmd`:

```
cmd /c "cd %CD%\mysql\bin && mysqld --install"
```

using just `start`:

```
start "" "cd %CD%\mysql\bin && mysqld --install"
```

I'd put a solution using both `start` and `cmd`, but you just don't need it.

BTW, if you can't just call `%CD%\mysql\bin\mysqld --install` directly, I'd look into using `pushd` instead of `cd`, so that you can call `popd` at the end of your overall script ... it's just good form to put your script user back in the directory in which they started.